# adding parts of a javabean together

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

How do I take the return values of some methods that I wrote in a bean and add them together for an return? For instance:

```
public double getPart1Average()  {               
        String[] average = new String[]{Part01, Part02, Part03};
                int sum = 0;
                for (String input : average)     {
                sum += Integer.parseInt(input);
                                            }      
                    return ((sum * (10) / (3)) * .25);
                                                 }
```

If I have six methods like mostly like this and I need to write a method to return a sum of these methods how would I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Just create a new [property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/properties.html) by supplying a new getter method.

Comment: just make object of bean class and get all six methods return value by their getter method and just concat them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question then I you just need this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Sum Of Average:: " + new Average().getSumOfAverage());
    }

    private double getSumOfAverage() {
        return getPart1Average() + getPart2Average() + getPart3Average(); // call all required method here
    }
```

Let me know if this is not what you want.

Comment: Did you notice `JSP` in OP's tags?